# Disable faint border shadow around StackLayout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When i have one StackLayout inside another one, there is a faint border shadow around it.
[image: Shadow around StackLayout]

I don't like the way it looks, is there a way to get rid of it ?

Here is XAML of the bottom pannel:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                     VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Button Text="&#8962;"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Text="Kontrola"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Label Text="Autorem zadání je Cermat.cz"
                   FontSize="Micro"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button Text="&#707;"
                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                FontSize="Title"
                BackgroundColor="Gray"
                BorderColor="Gray"
                IsEnabled="False"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: StackLayout doesnt have any border, could you post you xaml

Comment: Added XAML of the bottom pannel. As you can see there is a subtle grey border around the button "Kontrola" and the label. Both are only in a StackLayout with no frame.

Comment: My xamarin forms nuget package version is 4.4.0.991477, Here is my screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/MKAN9Bn it worked as normal. Here is my demo. https://github.com/851265601/fff   You can download it and test it in your application, if it is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Stacklayout:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                 HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                 VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
```

you are not setting the Spacing to 0, in the Microsoft Documentation for [Stacklayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout#spacing) it says:

> By default, StackLayout will add a 6px margin between views.

And that's why you se those lines, it's the spacing between the 3 elements you have inside horizontally. But it's weird why you even see those lines, because you are not setting the background color to white in those elements. i don't know if you ommited that, since i don't see you setting the border color to green too.

Comment: That's it. I was setting background color to white globally.

Comment: Worked in different where i was having horizontal line using box view but that was having blurred shoadow effect because of the spacing only